# JSON2.js or Native JSON Methods

Tags: json, browser

[JSON MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

[JSON ORG](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Since the addition of the JSON methods(parse, stringify) listed at the Mozilla site, should these methods be used in lieu of the files from JSON.org(json2.js)?

Comment: +1 for the links. Links are really very useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the native functions as they will get better performance and have a better memory footprint.  Consider json2.js to be a polyfill, something you only use if the browser doesn't support JSON.  A list of these browsers can be found here: http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON

```
if(!JSON || !JSON.parse || !JSON.stringify)
    document.write('<script src="json2.js"></script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Various javascript libraries already ask for native browser support before running parser in javascript. You can do it yourself by asking if there is global JSON object defined.